# Symfony2 JMS Serializer - modify certain values

Tags: symfony, serialization, symfony-2.8

I have to work with an existing project and I have to modify some data before they are being serialized. A simple example:

This is what my serializer returns at the moment:

```
[
  {
    "id": 3,
    "reward": "reg"
  }, 
  {
    "id": 4,
    "reward": "inv"
  }, 
]
```

And this is what I want returned:

```
[
  {
    "id": 3,
    "reward": "Registration"
  }, 
  {
    "id": 4,
    "reward": "inviting another user"
  }, 
]
```

I want to rewrite stupid strings that come from the database to actually readable outputs. So I have to run a `str_replace` over certain fields from certain entities. How can I achieve this?

I tried creating my own visitor, but that seems to only have the possibility to change "visitString", which is not specific enough. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can create Subscriber to `serializer.post_serialize` event, and modify data like this:

```
use JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\ObjectEvent;

    class RewardSerializerEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
    {
        /**
         * Returns the events to which this class has subscribed.
         *
         * @return array
         */
        public static function getSubscribedEvents()
        {
            return [
                ['event' => 'serializer.post_serialize', 'method' => 'onSerialize', 'class' => YourReward::class],
            ];
        }

        public function onSerialize(ObjectEvent $event)
        {
           /** @var YOURENTITY $object */
           $object  = $event->getObject();
           $visitor = $event->getVisitor();
           if ($visitor->hasData('reward')) {
                $reward = $object->getReward();
                switch ($reward) {
                    case 'reg':
                         $reward = "Registration";
                         break;
                    case 'inv':
                         $reward = 'inviting another user';
                         break;
                    default:
                       break;
                }
               $visitor->setData("reward", $reward);
           }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `serializer.post_serialize` event and you can replace your strings.

Read this document:
http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/event_system

Comment: How to I access a certain value in post_serialize ?

Comment: in your subscriber function;

`/** @var JsonSerializationVisitor $visitor */

        $visitor = $event->getVisitor();

        $entity = $event->getObject();`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply use Accessor annotation to explicitly set the getter.

http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#accessor

```
/** @JMS\Accessor(getter="getReward") */
private $reward;

public function getReward()
{
    switch ($this->reward) {
            case 'reg':
                return 'Registration';
            case 'inv':
                return 'inviting another user';
            default:
                return $this->reward;
        }
}
```